# Finding expectation of coordinates in random walk

Tags: expected-value, coordinate-systems

This is Example 2(i) of Sheldon Ross' A First Course in Probability.

I have a question about a variation of this problem:

> Consider a particle initially located at a given point in the plane, and suppose that it
> undergoes a sequence of steps of fixed length, but in a completely random direction.
> Specifically, suppose that the new position after each step is one unit of distance from
> the previous position and at an angle of orientation from the previous position that
> is uniformly distributed over (0, 2π).

[image]

The variation I have would be to find the expected value of the final point instead. My question is whether this is equal to $0$ as the expected value of the X-coordinate can be written as,

$$E(X) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} E(X_i)$$

and $X_i$ would just be equal to $\cos{\theta_i}$, where $\theta_i$ is the angle randomly chosen at each turn. Then,

$$E(X_i) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos{\theta_i} dx = 0$$

which means that the expected value of $X$ would be $0$. The same argument can be used for $Y$ to show that the expected coordinate would be $(0, 0)$

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: This is correct :)
Another way to view that is that $X$ and $-X$ distribute the same ,thus they have the same expectation, so it must be zero.